How to make Swagger documentation work behind external api authentication?
We have a setup, where our api authentication is done with 3rd party library in AWS Cloudfront. In our api, we create swagger documentation with a 3rd party library (reitit-swagger), so we can't tweak that.
We tried giving all swagger stuff a bypass without api authentication and it worked BUT all other swagger stuff is ok to be public except swagger.json, which contains all the details of our api.
How can we have a working swagger documentation behind api authentication without exposing swagger.json to the world?

The swagger.json file is machine-readable documentation for the API.  Typically, it is used to generate client bindings/libraries and GUI documentation (e.g. Swagger UI).
This means it's used when the client applications/libraries are being written, not when they're being run.
Because it is not (normally) used at runtime, it does not need API authentication.  (Even if it is used at runtime, the client library/app can use a local copy.)
It's best that documentation is accessible at no charge.  Microsoft and Google are good examples of this.  They make plenty of money even though most of their documentation is publicly accessible.
However, if you need to restrict the swagger.json for business reasons, just copy it to a human-facing support/documentation site, restricted to require a login.  In other words, use human authentication for it, not API authentication.
OpenAPI does not require that the API endpoint be on the same server as the JSON file.  There is a servers field allowing you to specify. This example is from the above link:
servers:
  - url: https://api.example.com/v1    # The "url: " prefix is required


Our documentation does not cost, but it must be protected with api keys.
How would copying swagger.json to another server help? Swagger documentation is generated automatically and the library produces the swagger.json and the needed references to it. So everything is automated, we do not touch the generated swagger files ourselves.

"Our documentation does not cost, but it must be protected with api keys. How would copying swagger.json to another server help?" I addressed both these concerns.  To protect it, you can provide it behind a human login, on a support/doc site.  That's also the reason for copying it (which can be automated).  An API client doesn't need the swagger.json at runtime.  A human does, when building a client.  That's why you want a site intended for human login.  Requiring API auth (rather than human auth) simply to download swagger.json is non-standard and puts the cart before the horse.

That said, I disagree with "Our documentation does not cost, but it must be protected with api keys.".  1. The swagger.json should not contain sensitive info. 2. Even if you consider the list of available functionality sensitive, remember that someone can simply authenticate, download the swagger.json, then redistribute it. 3. Major companies don't see any need to restrict access to swagger.json, even for highly commercial industries like AI: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/AzureOpenAI/inference/stable/2024-06-01/inference.json

Your authentication happens in AWS CloudFront. You have whitelisted all "swagger stuff". You could probably allow all "swagger stuff" excluding the swagger.json, but it won't work for a user visiting the page. The Swagger UI needs the swagger.json (or an equivalent openapi.json)... So if a user visits your Swagger UI unauthenticated, the user will see nonworking Swagger pages because he or she won't be able to load the necessary swagger.json.
Another idea is to generate the static web pages using a tool like swagger-ui-dist and host that publicly. You could do this in a build step of the API, so that the information is up to date with the actual implementation. Note that the swagger.json can likely be reverse engineered from this static code.
Most importantly, I don't see why you would be okay showing the API documentation, but not the swagger.json. They basically contain the same information... So why not share the swagger.json as well?

Thank you for your reply.
We can control the access to the swagger documentation with api keys, so our api won't be exposed to the world. The whitelisting works, yes, but the problem is exactly the swagger.json that our product owner has stated can't be exposed to the world.
I guess the static web pages are only option here.

@laalaa why does your product owner not want it exposed? Does your product owner realize the same information can be obtained from the static page, though a bit more obscured? Swagger is meant to be a blueprint to your API, simply secure your API or don't expose it.
